# Problemas al generar vista previa con JsPdf

Tags: javascript, jspdf

Hola un gusto en saludarles, espero me puedan ayudar. Yo he estado trabajando con JsPdf para generar reportes pdf desde Javascript. Pero desde hace un tiempo me di cuenta que el comando

```
pdf.output('dataurlnewwindow');
```

ya no me esta mostrando la vista previa sino que de una vez me descarga el documento, alguien me puede decir o explicar la razón ? y que puedo hacer para volver a generar la vista previa sin cambiar el JsPdf por otro ?

Comment: Bienvenido, @Mcesar1, a Stack Overflow, te sugiero que leas [cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) y que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para adaptarte mejor a esta platafomra.

Comment: Suena a que tu navegador por defecto descarga el archivo en vez de abrirlo

Comment: Muchas Gracias por la atención prestada. Al parecer es el navegador que esta configurado por defecto. Ya lo resolvi con tu ayuda @Alfabravo